# Identify which button in message was clicked

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm sending messages with Block elements(buttons) to users using Slack API (python-slackclient). Different users can get number of these and can click the buttons with a delay obviously, for example the next day.

I need to identify which button in which message was clicked.

After checking the documentation on Slack API pages it looks like *action_id* is the way to go as I can specify it in my request and assign it a unique value. I shall get the action_id back in response coming to my endpoint once user clicks one of the buttons which will allow me to match it with sent message.

Is this the correct way to achieve it? Are you aware any better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an action_id on your button in order to tie your button to a response action.
So if you have several buttons that should all trigger the same action, but you'd still need to know which of those buttons was clicked, maybe you could give them all the same action_id (so you can link them to the same action), but specify unique button values.

Comment: It is not possible to have the same `action_id` for multiple buttons inside of a Slack view. It's an unfortunate limitation that I'm trying to find out how to work around.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your action_ids are unique, BUT you can receive a message or an action using RegEx and thus still point them all to the same handler.

For example, this action handler receives all button presses where the action_id starts with "hello"

```
app.action(/^hello.*/, async ({ body, ack, say }: any) => {
  await ack();
  await say(`<@${body.user.id}> clicked the button`);
});
```